# Internet speed became slow in 14.04!

Tags: 14.04, internet

My internet speed got slow since a week, if I download anything using uGet or bitTorrent it downloads very slowly, but if I download any software from Ubuntu Software Center, it downloads it with usual speed. Yesterday updated one software (Android Studio), updates were also downloaded with regular speed. Why speed becomes slow if i use any download manager or bitTorrent or even if I download from browser?

Answer (score 1):

Ports which was used for update is opened in your Ubuntu machine by default, and you can open bit torrent port or any other software port in  firewall with the following command and this would increase the speed.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 'your port number' -j ACCEPT
```

and

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 'your port number' -j ACCEPT
```

Hope this helps!